# Eating/drinking before Birkat Kohanim

Tags: halacha, mitzvah, eating, birchas-kohanim, drinking

According to Halacha, one should not eat a meal before hearing the Shofar blown. Many such as rav Yosef Eliyahu Henkin were Machmir even when it comes to drinking. The source of this general principle of not eating before a mitzvah is in the Talmud of [Masechet Sukkah](https://www.sefaria.org/Sukkah.38a.5). My question is, can a Kohen eat and/or drink before Birkat Kohanim?

Comment: There's a parallel version of this question, which is can a cohen who ate/drank still duchen? Arguably, once he's eaten the rule of "maybe he's a bit drunk" applies like at mincha. Accordingly, places that have kiddush on Rosh Hashana before musaf should duchen at shacharis like on simchas torah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nitei Gavriel, Hilchos Yom Tov [60:9](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46543&st=&pgnum=414) says it's forbidden to eat a meal and it's best not to eat at all:

> אנשי מעשה נוהגים שלא לטעום מאומה קודם נ"כ, ואכילת קבע אסורה לכו"ע

Comment: FWIW, I confirmed this practice with a kohen friend.